# Angular 6 lazy loading module not found with 2 more apps in the directory in Build

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-aot

I am building angular apps multiple which have 3 apps

2 are build on angular V5
1 is on angular v6

I have declared lazy loading as

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  loadChildren: '../app/bima/bima.module#BimaModule',
  data: {
   breadcrumb: ''
  }
 },
 {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '',
  pathMatch: 'full'
 }
];
```

Furthermore I have tried using following solution.

- Using relative path `loadChildren: './...`
- Using absolute path starting with `loadChildren: 'src/app/...`
- tsconfig.app.json --> `BaseUrl: "./"`

and tried alot of things on google.

For development server its working good but when production build is run it gives error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 
"../app/bima/bima.module.ngfactory".
Error: Cannot find module "../app/bima/bima.module.ngfactory".
```

Apps are serving differently, My 3rd app based on angular 6 is not running and giving error

Comment: Loading a module lazily isn't for loading a different app. It's for loading a child module of the same app, lazily. If you have 3 different apps, then they need to be served on different base Hrefs, and you can only use regular links to go from one to the other.

Comment: Yeah I know and I have served them differently. 
My point is that lazy loading module in angular 6 app is not working. @JBNizet